# How to view an proxy object using geometry nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

Can I add a proxy object and use it for viewing only in the viewport and Render the original object instead when rendering using geometry nodes.

Let's take an example -
In the below Screenshot, I am scattering Suzzane, and I want Icosphere as a proxy, in simple words:- I want to view Icosphere in viewport and Suzzane in the render.
Is there any way to do this?
Is this possible using geometry Nodes?

[image: Sceenshot geometry nodes]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to do this using the *Switch* node. It only requires a minor modification to your original node group: place the switch node between the object info node and the instance on points node. You can then control the switch node with the *Is Viewport* node, as shown below:
[image]